# Is there any corobating evidence besides the Bible of the stories of Shadrach, Meschach, and Abednego?

Tags: history, babylonian-exile, daniel-book-of

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadrach,_Meshach,_and_Abednego

(AKA Chananya, Mishael, and Azarya)

The story is that these 3 people did not bow to a golden image. Then they got thrown into a fire. A miracle happened and they survived. The king is so impressed that he declared all people to respect Jewish God. Given that Babylon is a great kingdom, this must have been a very significant event.

That seems to be a very public miracle. Are there any historical record to corroborate this?

Comment: While IMO the question is on-topic here, you might get better answers from the new [history.se] site, where it's AFAICT _more_ on-topic, if you will.

Comment: Oh thank you. Yes I will ask them there too. I am just curious how much Judaism is based on mere faith like Christianity and how much they are based on real evidences. That's actually my main motivation in asking this. While I want to learn more about what jews actually believe, my ultimate aim is of course, the truth behind those beliefs rather than just beliefs. I think history may be a better channel.

Comment: @JimThio Regardless of what you learn at the History site, I just want to mention that you picked a most obscure story in a book which is not considered part of the "Prophets" to base such a search on.

Comment: @msh210 it appears that the History site is closed to the public.

Comment: Sorry. It's not an important event in judaism? I mean from the whole bible I am looking for verifiable claims about God's existence. This seems to be the most important sample. I mean where else? I can't find history stack so I asked in sceptic stack. I mean a king of a much stronger country admit that jewish God is "real". You don't think it's very important?

Comment: Nope, it's not a very improtant Jewish event.  Cyrus declaring the rebuilding of the Temple is more important/theologically significant and the Cyrus cylinder attests to it.  The fact is, for the past 1500 years, the "pagans" admitted that the "Jewish god" is "real".  When that first happened isn't so important.  Though it is a good question! :)

Comment: Re "I am just curious how much Judaism is based on mere faith like Christianity and how much they are based on real evidences. That's actually my main motivation in asking this.": Then that's what you should ask: not "is there external support" but "do we base our belief on external support". Two different questions.

Comment: @avi, re "a most obscure story": I wouldn't go that far. I suspect most fifth-grade _y'shiva_ students have heard the story.

Comment: If you ask most Jews what happened in the book of Daniel, I'm sure they will mention the story.  But if you ask them who Abednego is, I doubt they would know.

Comment: @avi The History site is now public.

Comment: @avi, re "If you ask most Jews what happened in the book of Daniel, I'm sure they will mention the story. But if you ask them who Abednego is, I doubt they would know.": Well, sure. We usually call him by his Hebrew name! `:-)`

Comment: Yeah but when a story is important and deeply part of Judaism, we use the names that the Sefer uses. For example, "The father of Banot Tzelofechad" instead of just saying "Tzelofechad"

Comment: @avi, both sets of names are in _Daniyel_ AFAIR. (And I call him "_Tz'lofchad_", but maybe that's just me.)

Comment: @msh210 yes, both sets of names are used in general, but only one set is used in reference to this actual story.

Comment: @avi: nonetheless, the Gemara and Midrashim consistently use their Hebrew names in reference to this story (Pesachim 117a-b, Kesubos 33b, etc.), so that's probably why it's better known to us Jews in that form.

Comment: I see. This is a very significant event for most sceptic like me because it's a public miracle. For example, when God spoke to Abraham, he spoke through "his head". No offense. But Abraham may be schizophrenic. But actual people sent to burn and somewhat alive in front of a king with no fear or intensive to lie is great. But again, there is no historical evidence corroborating it. History wrote that Darius worship Marduk and tolerant toward all others gods, not just YHWH and jews.

Comment: Yes I know about how ancestors of jews actually hear God speak in some mount. But they are all jewish. No offense. Your ancestor had axe to grind and actively slaughter those who believe differently. A sceptic could say that they wanted to justify genocide against Canaanites. Then there is this Jesus that perform miracles. But Benny Hinn also did that (falsely). Most evidence are cursory and miracles are not too public nor is it in front of famous prominent people at that time (except possibly Nicodemus)

Comment: @JimThio Two points: 1)We don't believe in Jesus, and we don't accept that he did any true miracles. He is no more legitimate to Jews than Benny Hinn or Sun Myung Moon, frankly. 2)If you're looking for fantastic public miracles, the splitting of the Red Sea and the Exodus from Egypt are much better choices, as well as the revelation at Sinai (which you've derided). I'm not sure you are interested in understanding the underpinning of Judaism so much as you are interested in degrading Judaism.

Comment: @Seth J. My intent is to know God without faith (if He exists). So I can share that to everyone especially my atheists/agnosis friend. I thought jews are "closest" to God given that well He (supposedly) chose you and stuff. I will ask about red sea (it's actually Reed sea) on my other questions. I'll ask Jesus' questions on christian stack. They both have the same problem. Only believers saw it. I also asked a nice Rabbi. Obviously his time is expensive. So I got to research a lot before asking anything :). Where else besides here?

Comment: You cannot know G-d without faith. We are enjoined to "Know" He exists, according to the RaMB"aM (Maimonides) Hil. Yesodei HaTorah 1:1, and that He is "true" (or "the truth" depending on the translation of ibid. 1:2). But this comes from a place of faith. You cannot prove His existence using the scientific method. You have to know it internally and accept that, whatever question arises that your studies in Torah have not yet answered and/or that science has not yet answered, the answer can be found with G-d and we have to keep seeking. This site can help, but it won't give you your answer.

Comment: And there are many rabbis who would love to talk to you. Don't overvalue his time. His job is to teach. If he doesn't have the time to teach you, he either doesn't consider you to be sincere or he is not a good teacher and you should ask someone else. Unless, of course, you've been hounding him day and night and not letting him sleep. Ultimately, if you really want to learn, then patience is the key. And attitude. Your questions generally seem to lean towards antagonism rather than curiosity.

Comment: @Seth J. I guess I was antagonistic. Well faith doesn't mean wrong. Say I have faith that I can be rich, then I work hard, then I get rich. By that time I know I can. I no longer need faith. Maybe God is like that too. Maybe some faith is necessary at first. If jews didn't get out of egypt, they'll never know God can split seas. He's playing hide and seek and as time goes by, we know more and more what He is not. For example, we know that His palace is not in mount olympus. Not last time I check google earth. We know he doesn't make miracles often. We know that by tons of debunked miracles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to find this PDF which claims that historical evidence gives tangential evidence to the story in Daniel.

http://www.biblehistory.net/Meshach_Shadrach_Abed-Nego.pdf

He mentions that the names of these three people are found on a 5 sided clay prism from Babylonia, but so far I've only found Christian sites that make reference to this pillar.  It seems this story plays a much larger roll in Christian theology than it does in Jewish teachings.

A small comment about "public" stories in Tanach.  Not all events that were done before all the people, were infact done before all the people of Israel.  For example, there is one story of a man forced to be intimate with a women before all the people on a rooftop.  Pure logistics would prove this to be impossible.  One might say that such a public act would be written about in many places, but on the other hand, such an act might have just been done in front of select people represetting "all the people of Israel" and not have been widely written about.

Comment: "forced to be intimate..."? Are you talking about Avshalom and his father's ten concubines (II Sam. 16:22)? If so, then he wasn't "forced" - it was of his own free will (at Achitophel's advice). As for "before the eyes of all Israel," that's pretty much parallel to saying nowadays that something was done "in front of all Americans"; it simply means that anyone who wanted could see it (not necessarily that everyone is actually there, though).

Comment: Curiously why the christians, rather than the jews, are the one more obsessed with proofing judaism?

Comment: @JimThio I don't know how to explain this in a short comment, but the concept of 'proofing Judaism' by supplying evidence that text in a religious documeny is historically accurate is complete nonsense.  We look to the text for religious and philosophical guidance, not for academic historical research.

Comment: @JimThio Let me put this another way.  If we went about trying to prove the historical accuracy of the books of Ketuvim, then we would in turn be destroying and uprooting Hudreds of Midrashim, and thousands of Dvrei torah that surround the stories. These Midrashim are based on a literary reading of the stories, and find puns and nuance to add meaning.  If you try to make these stories historically accurate, those puns and nuances lose all meaning.

Comment: @JimThio something I just learned over this Shabbat.  The Christian bible has 3 additional books/passages regarding this story which the Jewish Tanach does not have.  That might also explain their interest.

Comment: @avi It depends on the denomination. I only know about one passage, which is included in the Roman Catholic and Easter Orthodox Bibles but not Protestant, and it is important because it is a canticle sung during the Liturgy of the Hours.